# get_query_var('s') not working

Tags: search

When I use transposh plugin `get_query_var('s')` returns me blank. But I can get value of s by using $_GET['s']. So, my search functionality has been stopped. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you use exactly: `get_query_var['s']` notation?

Comment: Please, provide a sample code where the problem exists.

Comment: I have use `get_query_var('s')`

Comment: I am using default search functionality provided by theme. But If I activate transposh translation plugin my search functionality stops working. So, to debug issue I have printed out `get_query_var('s')`

Comment: So this works with the transposh plugin disabled? But when you enable it it doesn't?

Comment: close voting as it is plugin specific

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to use the following function somewhere in your template, whether in `functions.php` or somewhere.

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "s";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

It'll avail your `s` parameter from the URL into the `get_query_var('s')`.

Comment: `s` is a built-in query var, no need to add it :)

Comment: then the `get_query_var('s')` should work!

Comment: `s` is built-in variable still get_query_var('s') does not give me value of 's'

Comment: `get_query_var()` will only fetch public query variables. `s` is not on the list. See:http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables

Comment: not sure when it changed, but as of 05-2022, `s` is listed as a public query_var